# What is known about these "transparent" polytopes?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, terminology, convex-geometry, polytopes

I am looking for the name (if there is one), simple properties and possible literature for the following class of polytopes (by polytope I mean the convex hull of finitely man points in $\Bbb R^n,n\ge 2$). For lack of another name, I call them *transparent*.

> **Definition**. A polytope $P\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ is **transparent** if  there exists a direction $v\in\Bbb R^n$, so that lines through the vertices of $P$ with direction $v$ do not intersect the interior of $P$.

Another characterization is, that the shadow (projection) of $P$ onto a hyperplane has all the vertices of $P$ on its boundary. I called them transparent because, if made from glass with opaque vertices, it is possible to look through their interior without any vertices in the way.

I wonder whether such polytopes were discussd in the literature before and whether there is a classification of these.  I am especially interested in *centrally symmetric polytopes with vertices on the unit sphere*, but I think it is still interesting in the general case.

[image]

---

**Examples.** The following polytopes are transparent:

- Simplices, hypercubes and cross-polytopes of dimensions $\ge 2$.
- The [cuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron).
- Prisms and many of the [prismatoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prismatoid)
- Since being transparent is invariant under affine transformations, also [parallelepipeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) etc.

The following polytopes are *not* transparent:

- Regular polygons with $\ge 5$ vertices.
- The icosahedron, dodecahedron and [icosidodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosidodecahedron).

Comment: It is the intended projection on orthogonal coordinate planes what makes hypercubical symmetries (or axial scalings thereof, i.e. briques etc.) the main objects of interest. But infact, there are all quasiregular versions too. I.e. any polytope of the hypercubical symmetry with just a single node being ringed in ist Coxeter-Dynkin symbol. --- rk